# Flexbox container for react-big-calendar breaks the UI

Tags: css, flexbox, react-big-calendar

Here is the codesandbox **Click Open In New Window for full screen mode**:

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sun-sen7m?file=/src/App.js

The problem: when there is a display:flex container higher in HTML hierarchy react-big-calendar doesn't try to fit the page and breaks the UI.
You can delete display:flex property for .appWrapper class to see how it should work properly.

PS Setting max-width for .custom-calendar class in pixels or so is not an option because it loose real responsiveness this way (need to support mobile screens).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation site specifically states in the [Getting Started](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#intro) section:

> Also make sure that your calendar's container element has a height, or
> the calendar won't be visible

Place the Calendar within it's own container, and set it's height. Internally, the Calendar display uses flexbox for laying out it's content.